# What should $a$ be for the system of inequalities to have one solution?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

What should $a$ be for the system of inequalities to have one solution?

$$(1) \frac{3}{x-a}\geq 1 (2)\left | x-2a-2 \right | \leq 1$$

For them to have one solution, the solution must be an endpoint of an interval. (1) gives me $$x\leq a+3$$, but I don't know how to proceed from here. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first it's
$$\frac{3}{x-a}-1\geq0$$ or
$$\frac{3+a-x}{x-a}\geq0$$ or
$$a<x\leq 3+a.$$
The second it's
$$2a+1\leq x\leq3+2a.$$
Now, we see that an unique possibility it's $$3+a=2a+1.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the whole argument?

Comment: @Aleksandr Ask please a concrete question.

Comment: Where does the first line come from?

Comment: @Aleksandr The first it's the intervals method.  By the definition of $|\cdot|$ we have $|x|\leq a$ it's $-a\leq x\leq a$. Thus, the second it's $-1\leq x-2a-2\leq1$ or $2a+1\leq x\leq2a+3.$

Comment: Why can't $x-a$ be smaller than $0$?

Comment: @Aleksandr $3+a>a$. Take on $x$-axis points $a$ and $3+a$. You got three intervals: $(-\infty,a),$$(a,3+a]$ and $[3+a,+\infty).$ The sign of the expression can be $+$ on $(a,3+a]$ only. Draw it!